# Access children of copied uipanel (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created an uipanel in Matlab and placed some uicontrols on it. How can I access those uicontrols when I copy the panel?

**Example:**

```
panel_a=uipanel(figure);
editfield=uicontrol(panel_a, 'style','edit');
x=uitab(tabgroup);
panel_b=copyobj(panel_a,x);

tmp=panel_b.editfield.String;      <-- how do I write this?
```

How is `editfield` of `panel_b` accessed?

Comment: You either explicitly copy the edit box so it has a handle you specify or you parse the `'Children'` of `tmp` to find the handle to the copied object.

Comment: there are a lot of uicontrols to access, copying each would be annoying. what do you mean by parsing the 'children' of tmp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign the `uicontrol` a `Tag` value to begin with, you can use this to find the handle to it once you copy it to the new panel using [`findobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html).

```
% Assign a 'Tag' value specific to this uicontrol
editfield = uicontrol(panel_a, 'style', 'edit', 'tag', 'editfield');

% Copy your relevant objects
panel_b = copyobj(panel_a, x);

% Use findobj to locate the handle to the object of interest
tmp = findobj(panel_b, 'Tag', 'editfield')
```

Alternately, you could use `findobj` to find all edit boxes

```
tmp = findobj(panel_b, 'Style', 'edit');
```